# Builtin way to list file permissions in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

What are the options, using no external commands, to list a file's permissions?

`test` is a builtin, but would only work for the owner of the file AFAIK, I'm after the entire thing. Thought I was onto something with `inodes`, but I can't find a way to read those (with builtins!) either.

`bash` only, please. Any version and/or format is acceptable.

#### edit:

I'm aware there are myriad ways to do this using external commands (`stat`, `ls`, etc.), this is just a thought exercise -- nothing I'm doing "requires" a `builtin` only solution

#### edit2:

Glenn Jackman's loadable commands answer is technically correct, as it IS using a builtin. However, I think it just showcases my question was poorly defined.

Using pure `bash` (any version) `builtin` commands, as listed [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) in the manual, and other built in functionality of `bash` (redirection, substitution, keywords, other things I'm not even aware of...), on a `linux` system, how can I list the full permissions a file has? Output would be similar to any of the ones below, though an umask value would also work.

```
user@hostname$ stat test -c %A
-rw-rw-r--

user@hostname$ stat test -c %a
664
```

Comment: What causes the "no external commands" restriction? Do you actually mean "no fork()" or "no execv()" or do you mean "no external code that is not in the /bin/bash file already"?

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. Why does it have to be a builtin?

Comment: This is for a script that would check dependencies, environment variables, files, etc. If `type -t` returns `builtin`, I'm happy. As for the cause, there is none -- this is for fun.

No XY problem here, I'm aware this is perfectly doable with `stat`, `ls`, `find`, and probably countless others.

Comment: What do you mean by "built-in" here? Built into which program?

Comment: Commands that are a part of the shell, built into `bash`. A list is in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), under "Shell Builtin Commands"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plain bash, I think the best you can get is something like this: you get *your* permissions, not group or other.

```bsh
myperms() {
  local file=$1
  local perms=""
  if [[ -d $file ]]; then
    perms+='d'
  elif [[ -L $file ]]; then
    perms+='l'
  else
    perms+='-'
  fi
  [[ -r $file ]] && perms+='r' || perms+='-'
  [[ -w $file ]] && perms+='w' || perms+='-'
  [[ -x $file ]] && perms+='x' || perms+='-'
  echo "$perms $file"
}
```

Then:

```bsh
$ myperms /bin/bash
-r-x /bin/bash
$ touch afile
$ myperms afile
-rw- afile
$ chmod u+x afile
$ myperms afile
-rwx afile
$ ln -s afile alink
$ myperms alink
lrwx alink
$ chmod u-wx afile
$ myperms alink
lr-- alink

$ ls -l afile alink
-r--r--r-- 1 glennjackman staff 0 Dec 16 14:28 afile
lrwxr-xr-x 1 glennjackman staff 5 Dec 16 14:29 alink -> afile
```

Comment: I agree, this is as far as I got too. But it seems weird to me that you'd only be able to check your own permissions with builtins, and not list or modify them.

Comment: Why would you need bash to modify file permissions when chmod exists?

Comment: @bash_problem_haver Shells (including bash) specialize in handing off tasks to other programs, and generally only have builtins for things that *can't* be done externally (like `cd` and `alias`) or are so frequently used that doing them without creating a new process is worthwhile for performance reasons (like `echo` and `[`). Getting a file's full permissions doesn't fit either of those, so it's not surprising it's not a built-in capability.

Comment: @GordonDavisson This helped me understand a lot, thank you. It seems the preferred method is to check return codes for failure instead of checking permissions, so it makes sense listing permissions is mostly unused. I'm still left wondering about `chmod` -- is there ways to `chmod` without using the system call `chmod()`? (But this should probably be its own question, I think)

Answer (score 1):

With bash version 5, there are "loadable commands" -- commands that are not builtin bash commands, but can be enabled such that they become builtins:

1. clone the bash git repo: https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash
2. `./configure --prefix=/path/where/you/want/it/installed`
3. make && make install
4. `stat` is not a "supported" loadable, even though it exists here, so

   1. `cd ./examples/loadables`
   2. `make others`
   3. `cp stat /path/where/you/want/it/installed/lib/bash`

Then

1. Launch a bash shell: `/path/where/you/want/it/installed/bin/bash`
2. set a shell variable: `BASH_LOADABLES=/path/where/you/want/it/installed/lib/bash`
3. enable the stat command: `enable -f stat stat`
4. and use it: `stat -A statarray /some/file`

`stat` populates an associative array. A demo (using the default array named "STAT")

```bsh
$ ~/bash/5.0/bin/bash

$ echo $BASH_LOADABLES_PATH
/Users/glennjackman/bash/5.0/lib/bash

$ enable -f stat stat

$ stat ~/.bashrc

$ declare -p STAT
declare -A STAT=([nlink]="1" [link]="/Users/glennjackman/.bashrc" [perms]="0644" [inode]="14482796" [blksize]="4096" [device]="16777220" [atime]="1574454147" [type]="-" [blocks]="8" [uid]="502" [size]="2767" [rdev]="0" [name]="/Users/glennjackman/.bashrc" [mtime]="1574454147" [ctime]="1574454147" [gid]="20" )

$ for key in "${!STAT[@]}"; do printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${STAT[$key]}"; done
nlink   1
link    /Users/glennjackman/.bashrc
perms   0644
inode   14482796
blksize 4096
device  16777220
atime   1574454147
type    -
blocks  8
uid 502
size    2767
rdev    0
name    /Users/glennjackman/.bashrc
mtime   1574454147
ctime   1574454147
gid 20
```

To automatically set the BASH_LOADABLE_PATH variable, I put in my ~/.bashrc:

```bsh
# for loadable builtins
bash_root=${BASH%/bin/bash}
[[ -d "$bash_root/lib/bash" ]] && BASH_LOADABLES_PATH="$bash_root/lib/bash"
unset bash_root
```

Comment: I wasn't aware commands could be made into builtins, cool! However, I do feel that this method goes against the spirit of the question, as this is just turning an external command into a builtin. I'll edit the question to clarify, but thank you.